# Need block alignment in html like stairs

Tags: html

I have to align the boxes in stairs format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbLwP.png)

I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Well this is not really a question about a problem, it's more like, please tell / teach me how to do this: Well you can do this with CSS and some rules very easily.

Comment: Maybe you hire a developer? In case you are the developer - better go through CSS tutorials how to position things in general. You can also use some tricks. For example the vertical line could be a background image that gets stretched vertically and you just use more and more padding.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked and no markup is provided.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use CSS-Grid together with CSS-selectors to target the specific cards that need to be styled. We can use the *:nth-child* selector to select every third card, as well as every third card starting from the second card. Then, we can add margins to these selected cards to achieve the desired layout. Hope this helps.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates this solution:

```css
body {
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px 40px;
}

.grid__item {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin-top: 30px;
}


.grid__item:nth-child(3n) {
   margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful. Thank you julbrn!